# Permissions in Windows Server, ASP.Net Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Hey, i will try to be as clear as possible:

I have a site on domain1. I need to open a ModalDialog with a Page on domain2. My Domain2 is protected not to allow anonymous access so i get a login window like:
[image]

My problem is, for this one functionality, i want users to be able to see that ASPX, through the ModalDialog, without authenticating.
I tried using the ftp way:
   http://user:password@www.domain.com/uploadcv.aspx
and i get a javascript error.

My site is hosted in IIS6, Windows Server 2003 and i have full access to the server.

Can anyone help me here? Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site is protected, how will the user access without authentication. What is the authentication scheme being used ?

Comment: well, i disabled Anonymous Access in Directory Security and i added a windows user to have read and right access. 
I would like to allow anonymous access only for this aspx page. Is this even remotely possible?

Comment: Technically yes, you can put this page into its own virtual folder and configure it for anonymous access in web.config. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399501/anonymous-access-to-aspx-page-fails

Comment: Perhaps you should put that helpful comment in the answer since the current answer text looks more like questions (which would otherwise belong as a comment).